# Prove a set is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $A$ $\subset$ $M$ such that $A$ ≠ Ø and $A$ ≠ $M$.

If the boundary of $A$ = Ø, prove that $M$ is disconnected.

I know I'm supposed to find an intersection that is empty in order to show it is not connected but I am unclear about how to do this with regard to the boundary of A since the boundary is the empty set.

**Update WIP**

Let $A$ $\subset$ $M$ such that $A$ ≠ Ø and $A$ ≠ $M$. Suppose the boundary of $A$ = Ø.

Then we have that the $cl(A) ∩ cl(A^c)$ is the empty set, which implies that $A$ is both open and closed.

Then $∃$ open subsets $U,V$ such that $A$ = $U$ and $A^c$ = $V$ and $M$ = $U ∪ V$. Therefore, $M$ is disconnected.

Comment: Hint: If $A$ has no boundary, what does it imply for its openness and closedness?

Comment: That it is both open and closed?

Comment: Yes. Now consider the complement of $A$ and the definition of connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contrapositive argument. 
First show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$ and $X\setminus A$ for some subset $A$ of $X$, then $C$ intersects the boundary of $A$. Then

> prove that if $A$ is a non-empty proper subset of $M$ such that $M$ is connected, then Boundary of $A$ is non-empty.

Since $M$ is connected and $\emptyset\neq A\neq M $, we have $M$ intersects both $A$ and $M\setminus A$ and so $M$ intersects the boundary of $A$, i.e. $M\cap \operatorname{Bd}(A)\neq \emptyset$. Hence $\operatorname{Bd}(A)\neq \emptyset$.